# NodeJS events on('connect') error

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently I have started learning Node.js with "Node.js in Action" book. In chapter there is following listing:

```
var events = require('events');
var net = require('net');

var channel = new events.EventEmitter();
channel.clients = {};
channel.subsriptions = {};

channel.on('join', function (id, client) {
    this.clients[id] = client;
    this.subsriptions[id] = function (senderId, message) {
        if (id !== senderId) {
            this.clients[id].write(message);
        }
    };
    this.on('broadcast', this.subsriptions[id]);
});

var server = net.createServer(function (client) {
    var id = client.remoteAddress + ':' + client.remotePort;
    client.on('connect', function () {
        channel.emit('join', id, client);
    });
    client.on('data', function (data) {
        data = data.toString();
        channel.emit('broadcast', id, data);
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```

I ran code:

```
node chat_server.js
```

Then opened new terminal and connected to chat_sever:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
```

Then again opened new terminal window and connected to chat_server. The book says:

> "If you open up a few command lines, you’ll see that anything typed in
>   one command line is echoed to the others. "

I tried to type in one terminal but nothing echoed in others. What can be problem? I am running Ubuntu 12.04

**EDIT:**

I tried to debug this part:

```
client.on('connect', function () {
        console.log('joined ' + id);
        channel.emit('join', id, client);
    });
```

but it does not show me "joined message" even if I open several terminals.

Comment: You can debug from chat_server.js by using console.log. From a quick look i'd say that the message is not broadcasted to all users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved my problem by the help of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19342910/when-is-the-connect-event-in-nodejs-net-module-emitted):

> on the server side, the socket is already connected when you get the
>   callback, and the event you're trying to listen to isn't emitted on an
>   already connected socket.

So, I emitted 'join' outside of client.on('connect'). In other words this code:

```
client.on('connect', function () {
        channel.emit('join', id, client);
    });
```

does nothing. And it must be replaced by:

```
channel.emit('join', id, client);
```